# Dynamic DropDownFormField returns null on Submit Button

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a page where user can input their exam result which are **subject** and **grade**.

On the page, user need to click the add subject button to add another subject depending on how many subject they have. User also can remove subject by clicking the remove subject button.

The problem is only **TextFormField** value submitted. How to get the data for **DropDownFormField** if the form created dynamically?

I have tried the read the data using the **onChanged** function of the drop down and yes the data was stored to the variable **gradeController** but it returns null when I submit the data.

This is the model

```
class SubjectGrade {
  final String? name;
  final String? grade;

  SubjectGrade(this.name, this.grade);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'SPM: name = $name, grade = $grade';
  }
}
```

This is the form

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testing_app/models/education_model.dart';

class EducationBackgroundForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const EducationBackgroundForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EducationBackgroundFormState createState() =>
      _EducationBackgroundFormState();
}

class _EducationBackgroundFormState extends State<EducationBackgroundForm> {
  final nameTECs = <TextEditingController>[];
  final gradeTECs = <String?>[];
  final forms = <Form>[];

  Form createForm() {
    TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
    String? gradeController;
    nameTECs.add(nameController);
    gradeTECs.add(gradeController);

    final grades = ['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'C+', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G'];

    DropdownMenuItem<String> buildMenuItem(String item) => DropdownMenuItem(
          value: item,
          child: Text(item),
        );

    return Form(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: nameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Subject Name',
                        labelText: 'Subject ${forms.length + 1}',
                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                        contentPadding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 5),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          value: gradeController,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          iconSize: 36,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                              color: Colors.black),
                          items: grades.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              gradeController = value;
                            });
                          },
                          hint: const Text("Grade"),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    forms.add(createForm());
  }

  saveSPMResultToFirebase() {
    List<SubjectGrade> entries = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      final name = nameTECs[i].text;
      final grade = gradeTECs[i].toString();
      entries.add(SubjectGrade(name, grade));
    }
    debugPrint(entries.toString());
    //Navigator.pop(context, entries);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text("SPM Result", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: forms.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return forms[index];
            },
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    forms.add(createForm());
                  }),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Add Subject',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 5),
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    if (forms.length > 1) {
                      forms.removeAt(forms.length - 1);
                    }
                  }),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Remove Subject',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
            onPressed: () {
              saveSPMResultToFirebase();
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Update',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I submit the form, the debug output I get from the submit function for grade is null.

Output:

```
[SPM: name = English, grade = null]
```

Comment: did your dropdown value change when you select something from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add value of `DropDownButton` in `onChanged` method not at top of create form.
change your code to this:

**First Delete `gradeTECs.add(gradeController);` line from top of `createForm()`**.

```
Form createForm() {
    TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
    String? gradeController;
    nameTECs.add(nameController);
    // gradeTECs.add(gradeController);  <==== DELETE THIS LINE.
```

**Add `gradeTECs.add(gradeontroller);` in `onChanged` method of `DropdownButtonFormField`**

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        value: gradeController,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        iconSize: 36,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                            color: Colors.black),
                        items: grades.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            gradeController = value;
                            gradeTECs.add(gradeController); <=== ADD HERE ==>
                          });
                        },
                        hint: const Text("Grade"),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: I see, so that's why I'm getting the null value. It solved my problem. Thanks